# Unable to Serialize and deserialize an UserControl

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization, mvvm

I made an application with MVVM in C# (WPF). I am facing an error when serializing and  deserializing the user interface from XML to WPF.

I am adding the control dynamically but on deserializing it is giving me an error as shown in image:

[image]

Here is my code. Please help me making the serializing and deserializing work.

```
   <UserControl x:Class="DecisionSuite.Creator.SetValue"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DecisionSuite.Creator"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="360" d:DesignWidth="800">
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionTemplate">        
                <local:SetValueSet ></local:SetValueSet>
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="LightGray" Background="LightGray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="Set Value"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Grid.Row="1"  BorderBrush="LightGray">
                <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SelectionTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SetValueModels}"/>            
            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            </Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Command="{Binding RefreshList}">
                <Viewbox >
                    <TextBlock Text="Add New Item" Margin="0" Padding="5" RenderTransformOrigin="1.079,1.079"></TextBlock>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Comment: Press Copy exception detail to clipboard.  Then open Notepad and "PASTE".  Post exception from notepad.  Break instruction into 3 lines so you can tell which part of the instruction is failing.

Comment: I am getting below error...  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=918
  Message=Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate' to an object of type 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'.  Error at object 'SelectionTemplate', Line 1 Position 918.
  NameContext=Resources
  Source=PresentationFramework

Comment: I cannot tell where line position 918 is located.  The error is probably due to the xml not being compatible with the xaml.  Break instructions into pieces and find where 918 is located.

Comment: How to check I am trying to identity but not getting any solution ,.

Comment: You are getting a Resource Dictionary Error.  See if this link helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: The standard Net Library Serialze method does not work with ditcionaries.  I think your rows and columns settings in the xml/xaml are using dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

You should not serialize User Controls, but instead serialize their data, because User Controls are basically your User Interface, like the TextBox, Button, etc..

You should serialize the data required to re-create the User Control only, and then design your User Control to allow re-construction from the serialized data and as a new User Control. Then your problem would be solved.